Keycloak - let user choose another user based on matching attribute
I'm trying to understand if Keycloak could be useful in this scenario.

user userX enters correct credentials
based on a given user attribute (ie. attributeX=xyz), Keycloak checks if any other user matches attributeX=xyz: ie. user1, user2 and user3
user is given possibility to proceed with login with one of the matched users: userX, user1, user2 and user3

thanks a lot
nicola

You means if user has no attributeX=xyz ,  she/he should not be allowed to log in even if he/she enter correct credential (username and password)?

thanks @BenchVue - he should be able to login anyway with original user userX (just updated the question for clarity)

I try to maven compile to start SPI with "keycloak-server-spi" but any version has problem at "org.keycloak.Config". I am stuck now, sorry.

You mean code customization is required in your opinion?

I try to make pom.xml with "keycloak-server-spi" without any code for starting SPI.
But I got an error at "org.keycloak.Config" when I ran 'mvn clean build' So I can't try to apply SPI for your problem.

@BenchVue I'm sorry I'm not sure I follow - could you share a github repo about this? I developed some keycloak extensions but anything could be the root cause about this without full source code available

I can run user provider SPI  demo with Keycloak v 21.1.0 in here. It did not address your question but I can built SPI jar  and apply to Keycloak.

What you're describing is called "impersonation". Keycloak does support impersonation, as discussed in keycloak's documentation . Just recognize that you'll want to make sure you limit which clients can impersonate users as this is a very security-sensitive operation.

thanks Dave - I'm aware of impersonation but I was thinking about a step before, therefore avoiding impersonation in the first level if user could be prompted to choose a different user during login flow? similar to how it's prompted to update the profile before completing login
